# How to pass a TextBox Object as a parameter to a method using c#

Tags: c#, methods, textbox, telerik

I want to pass a textbox object to a function where this function then validated the key processed on "KeyPress" event.

I have created a method inside a class called "common" like this

```
public void PreventInput(Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox tb, KeyPressEventArgs e, bool isDouble = true)
{

    string input = tb.Text;

    if (isDouble)
    {
        if ((Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            || (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            || ((e.KeyChar == '.') && (input.Contains(".") == false))
        )
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if ((Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            || (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        )
        {
            return;
        }

    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Then when I want to call this function inside keyPress Event, I do this

```
private void InputUnitPrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Common.PreventInput(sender, e, true);

}
```

but for some reason calling this method is giving me an error.

```
cannot convert from 'object' to 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox

RM.Common.PreventInput(Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs, bool)' has some invalid arguments
```

this code works with no issue but I am trying to avoid re-writing the code over and over everytime I want to restrict an input to number only

```
private void InputUnitPrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

    string input = (sender as Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox).Text;

    if ((Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        || (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        || ((e.KeyChar == '.') && (input.Contains(".") == false))
    ){
        return;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The question is how to get the `PreventInput` method to work without the errors.

**Edited**

based on the feedback below, I tried the following (and still did not work)

```
    public bool PreventInput(string input, KeyPressEventArgs e, bool isDouble = true)
    {

        if (isDouble)
        {
            if ((Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                || (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
                || ((e.KeyChar == '.') && (input.Contains(".") == false))
            )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if ((Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                || (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            )
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

and I call it like this

```
e.Handled = Common.PreventInput((sender as Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox).Text, e, true);
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass the control instead of just the text? The method should validate the input and leave the action to it's caller. On that way it is reusable and doesn't depend on any control.

Comment: so I can check the value of the presses button

Comment: i have shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27893123/284240) how you can check the value/text in the method but do whatever you want in the button-click handler according to the return value of the validation method.

Comment: How is it not working after making the changes? `sender` IS a `Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `sender` from `Object` to `RadTextBox`:

```
var txt = (Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox) sender;
Common.PreventInput(txt, e, true);
```

But why do you want to pass the control instead of just the text? The method should validate the input and leave the action to it's caller. On that way it is reusable and doesn't depend on any control.

So you could write it in this way:

```
public bool ValidateInput(string input, bool isDouble = true)
{
    bool isValid;
    //  insert your logic here ...
    return isValid;
}
```

now handle the return value as desired:

```
var txt = (Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox) sender;
e.Handled = Common.ValidateInput(txt.Text, true);
```

Comment: I tried this and it still not working. Please check my updated question I put the function where I only pass the text and it is not working for some reaon

Comment: still now working event with `e.Handled = Common.ValidateInput(txt.Text, true);`

Comment: @Mike: it doesn't work because you have not used my suggested code. You are still trying `e.Handled = true;` in the method which it should not need. Try my edited answer (i didn't see the unnecessary `KeyPressEventArgs` in the first place). **Edit** What means "not working"? However, good luck, i have to go to bed now ;)

Comment: I have updated my code and with that is still not working. I will update my question now to show you my current code. this is the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'RM.Common.PreventInput(string, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs, bool)`

Comment: it worked after making the method static :)  thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Convert the object to a textbox first:

```
Common.PreventInput(sender as Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox, e, true);
```

Your logic can be somewhat simplified a little as well:

```
public void PreventInput(Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox tb, 
    KeyPressEventArgs e, bool isDouble = true)
{
    string input = tb.Text ?? string.Empty;

    if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (isDouble && e.KeyChar == '.' && !input.Contains("."))
    {
        return;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```